# Migrate AngularJS to Angular 8 with iframe

Tags: angularjs, angular, migrate

So, my client wants me to migrate his AngularJS page to the newest Angular 8 framework.
But he also wants to add some features to the current AngularJS application. 
The workflows is like:
1. Migrate AngularJS to Angular 8
2. Sill maintain the old Angular JS app when there is new stuff coming in the old code.

The app has a static header navigation. So my idea was to build the header in Angular 8 and putt the old Angular JS app to the root of Angular 8 via iframe. 
So when the user clicks on the nevigation in the Angular 8 app he gets router to the correct Angular JS app which will be renderd in the iframe of the Angular 8 app.

So the idea behind this is to migrate the pages page by page but still maintain the old AngularJS app if needed.

Is this possible?

I hope somebody can help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first for migration i suggest you to use  This [migration guide](https://update.angular.io/)

At second, i have worked on an application where i used both Angular Js and angular8, the only problem that i have got was with rootes, i  couldn't usr routes in angular.

**How did i do ?**

I called the angular js and the transposed angular 8 files in the same jsp via `<script></script>` 
This is an example of my jsp with an angular 8 application called pointe, and angulars js application called employee

```
    <%@ include file="init.jsp" %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/angulars/pointe/styles.css"/>

    <app-root></app-root>

    <script src="/angulars/pointe/runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="/angulars/pointe/runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="/angulars/pointe/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="/angulars/pointe/polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="/angulars/pointe/scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/angulars/pointe/main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="/angulars/pointe/main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>

    <script src="/angulars/employee/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/angulars/employee/js/app.js"></script>
```

I think that it also works if you load your script into  an iframe, 
   but any ways you have to wrap all this code in a container.

And finally i do really not recommand you to do it, because i had a lot of troubles with libraries that are loaded in angular js and angular 8